# prebuilt_static_library on android

Tags: android-ndk, static-libraries

I need to use fftw3 library in my android project. The library was compiled using a slightly modified script from [this guide](http://www.cmumobileapps.com/2011/08/31/compiling-open-source-libraries-with-android-ndk-part-2/)

Here it is

```
INSTALL_DIR="`pwd`/jni/fftw3"
SRC_DIR="`pwd`/../fftw-3.3.2"
NDK_ROOT=$ANDROID_NDK

echo $INSTALL_DIR
echo $SRC_DIR

cd $SRC_DIR

export PATH="$NDK_ROOT/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/:$PATH"
export SYS_ROOT="$NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/"
export CC="arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=$SYS_ROOT"
export LD="arm-linux-androideabi-ld"
export AR="arm-linux-androideabi-ar"
export RANLIB="arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib"
export STRIP="arm-linux-androideabi-strip"

mkdir -p $INSTALL_DIR
./configure --host=arm-eabi --build=x86-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=$INSTALL_DIR LIBS="-lc -lgcc"

make
make install
```

Dir tree in jni of my android project

```
ls -R
.:
Android.mk  Application.mk  fftw3  wavfile

./fftw3:
Android.mk  bin  include  lib  share

./fftw3/bin:
fftw-wisdom  fftw-wisdom-to-conf

./fftw3/include:
fftw3.f  fftw3.f03  fftw3.h  fftw3l.f03  fftw3q.f03

./fftw3/lib:
libfftw3.a  libfftw3.la  pkgconfig

./fftw3/lib/pkgconfig:
fftw3.pc

./fftw3/share:
info  man

./fftw3/share/info:
dir  fftw3.info  fftw3.info-1  fftw3.info-2

./fftw3/share/man:
man1

./fftw3/share/man/man1:
fftw-wisdom.1  fftw-wisdom-to-conf.1

./wavfile:
Android.mk  wavfile.cpp  wavfile.h
```

jni/Android.mk

```
include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
```

jni/wavfile/Android.mk (wavfile myself written .cpp and .h)

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := wavfile
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := wavfile.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

jni/fftw3/Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := fftw3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/libfftw3.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := include
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

jni/Application.mk

```
APP_STL:=gnustl_static
```

output of ndk-build

```
Compile++ thumb  : wavfile <= wavfile.cpp
Prebuilt       : libgnustl_static.a <= <NDK>/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi/
SharedLibrary  : libwavfile.so
Install        : libwavfile.so => libs/armeabi/libwavfile.so
```

and nothing about fftw3.

Ассording to the ndk documentation

```
A prebuilt module does not build anything. However, a copy of your prebuilt
shared library will be copied into $PROJECT/obj/local, and another will be
copied and stripped into $PROJECT/libs/<abi>.
```

fftw3 libraries are not there. What is wrong?

Thank you.

.

Answer (score 1):

fft3 static library is there. You have listed them, intact. It's under.

```
./fftw3/lib:
libfftw3.a  libfftw3.la  pkgconfig
```

When you do ndk-build on the root Android.mk file, the shared library `libwavfile.so` gets created and your `libfftw3.la` should be embedded inside `libwavfile.so`. You load or include the `libwavfile.so` in your java file and start using APIs in fftw3 library and also those that you defined in `wavfile.cpp`.

Hope that helps.